# how do i access the message from the apprequests in Graph api explorer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

how to extract the message from app request?
(The message is not shown in the json format when submit is clicked. the message in left side tree representation appears dim. i have ticked all permissions while creating the access token.)
later i need to do it in objective c iOS
[image: Graph api explorer]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of **Facebook GraphAPI**. See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/280585148970245/)

It says the bug will be investigated and resolved soon. Patiently wait.

Comment: i was also looking for a solution.  the message from the app request wouldn't come.                                                                                                     anyways thanks anil